# `Error in as.unit(e1) : object is not coercible to a unit` in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Running the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.6) +
  theme(
    text = element_blank(),  # Remove text elements
    line = element_blank(),  # Remove line elements
    rect = element_blank()   # Remove rectangle elements
  )
```

returns the following error:

```
Error in `as.unit()`:
! object is not coercible to a unit
```

Using `theme_void()` instead eliminated the error, but I don't understand what causes the error. Can anyone help clarify?

EDIT:

I tried removing each theme object individually (e.g., removed `line`, ran `text` and `rect`, etc.) and re-ran the same code.

It seems like the issue is related to the `text = element_blank()` because the code below ran without an error.

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.6) +
    theme(
      line = element_blank(),
      rect = element_blank(),
      )
```

Adding `text = element_blank()` causes the error for some reason.

EDIT2: I am running R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31) and ggplot2_3.5.0.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Can you include your ggplot version and R version in the question please?

Comment: Looks like a bug that could use some reporting

Comment: @AllanCameron - Issue replicated using `ggplot2_3.5.0` and `R 4.3.2` using Win10. Error differed slightly: `Error in as.unit(e1) : object is not coercible to a unit`. I've only ever used `axis.text = element_blank()` etc. so can't say if the issue occurred in previous versions.

Comment: @AllanCameron I am running R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31) and ggplot2_3.5.0.